# Android device wake up via a paired bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.2-jelly-bean, wakeup

I have an Android device on Jelly Bean, and i want it to wake up when an already paired device is detected within the bluetooth range.
I guess it's a service broadcast receiver but i don't know how it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`.

Inside a BroadcastReciever:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
  if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction()))
  {

     int bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);

       if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
        {
              // wake up 
        }           

  }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if the phone is asleep (screen off, no wakelock)?

Comment: Can this be used by an app developer to wake up the app?

Comment: Interesting I receive EXTRA_BOND_STATE only after device is first time paired with phone. Not every time if phone is near to BLE device.